# Processing of form with redirect [plesk/zend]

Tags: zend-framework, plesk

I am using Plesk Sample 1.5-1 as a base, but stuck on how to process POST w/parameters.

My form is a 'text' element and 'ok' submit button and below that is a list that will change based on the value of the 'text' element (external XML call).

Inside IndexController, in the ->getRequest->isPost() area, I have a redirect line:

```
$this->_helper->json(array('redirect' => pm_Context::getBaseUrl()));
```

Do I have to manually pass the parameters on this line?  Or does the controller know because I created a pm_Form_Simple() and added elements?  Right now if I am outside the ->isPost block, the parameters are null, so that is why I am thinking I have to manually pass them along.

Do I need something like this?

```
$this->_redirector->gotoSimple('my-action',
                               'my-controller',
                                null,
                                array('exampleText' => $form->getValue('exampleText'));
```

I guess am just not understanding how the POST works.

I have looked at the Zend Guestbook example, but it is different enough from Plesk that I can't mentally translate it...and it doesn't redirect to the same page, it redirects some where else.

Ultimately, I want to set the 'exampleText' parameter with a "start date" and after the POST call, make an external XML call and fill out the list...  I can make the XML call, but can't get the workflow around empty form -> fill out form and press "ok" -> post processing

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the pm_Form_Simple needs JSON I didn't notice that my orig code had JSON but didn't encode the new code...